# How to argue that $f(x,y,z)=-x^2-xy-y^2+4yz-8z^2+2xz$ has a global maximum?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let  $f(x,y,z)=-x^2-xy-y^2+4yz-8z^2+2xz$.

I know $f$ has a local maximum at $(0,0,0)$ but how do I argue that this is also the global maximum. The solution provided simply states it is a global maximum because the function is negative everywhere else. This isn't obvious to me by inspecting $f$ and I don't know any other methods to tackle this type of problem.

Comment: Did you try Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: The mean value theorem or the concept of convex functions are helpful in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard mathematical tool for dealing with quadratic forms is to represent them by a symmetric matrix and then diagonalize the matrix. In this case, all three eigenvalues are negative, so all values of the quadratic form are negative (other than the zero at the origin). In fact, here you don't even have to diagonalize - the characteristic polynomial has all negative coefficients, which shows that no eigenvalue can be positive (and symmetric matrices always have a full complement of real eigenvalues, so they must all be negative).

Answer (score 2):

Completing the squares in a systematic way you get
$$f(x,y,z)=-\bigl(x+{1\over2}y-z\bigr)^2-{3\over4}(y-2z)^2-4z^2\ ;$$
whence $f$ is a negative definite quadratic form. It follows that
$$f(x,y,z)< f(0,0,0)=0\qquad\forall \>(x,y,z)\ne(0,0,0)\ .$$